# How feasible would it be to move a Kuiper Belt object (a good sized one) into an orbit around Mars?

Tags: terraforming

Reason I'm asking, it's seemed to me that the best way to create an atmosphere on Mars is by moving an icy planetoid/comet/Kuiper Belt object and basically smashing it into mars, though I think a low orbit, perhaps near the Roche Limit where it breaks apart pretty easily would be more practical than a crash landing.

Roughly speaking, comets are mostly too small to be that interesting.   To create a 1 ATM atmosphere you'd need something in the range of 120 KM in radius - figuring some of it would be water, some of it would be dust and rock, some of it would be CO<sub>2</sub> that you'd want to turn into plant life.

In terms of moving the object, you could do a gravity assist around Neptune and using Neptune, you could adjust the trajectory either towards mars or towards another planet for another gravity assist.   The object could be moved by large mirrors, melting some of the ices on the surface creating a propulsion or by explosions.   I think that would be the easiest way.

And once in orbit, the process is rather simple, the sun would melt some of the lower freezing point ices, and in a near roche limit orbit, it could be broken apart fairly easily given the tidal forces already in play.

Figuring a Kuiper Belt object is made up of a combination of dust, frozen H<sub>2</sub>O, CO<sub>2</sub>, CH<sub>4</sub>, NH<sub>3</sub> some frozen N<sub>2</sub>, a bit of CO, maybe some NO, some O<sub>2</sub>, a sprinkling of more complex molecules, a little Argon, Hydrogen and Helium, it's not something you'd want to breath, but it would create atmospheric pressure, perhaps similar to earth.   (120 KM radius, figure 1.5 density, mass would be about 10 billion billion KG - about twice the mass of the earths' atmosphere, but if half of it is rock, dust and water-ice - then you've got about what you need for 1 ATM on mars).

So, while this would by no means be easy or quick, it certainly seems possible - given a thousand years or so, and we'd want to be careful not to miscalculate and send a 100 KM radius object into a path where it might hit earth - as that would be a bad day, but, with care, this should be doable - so you have an object in orbit around mars that's gradually breaking up and it gives the planet an atmosphere and water.

Is there a way to turn this quantity of NH<sub>3</sub> and CH<sub>4</sub> as well as CO and NO and other things we maybe wouldn't want to breath, into N<sub>2</sub> and CO<sub>2</sub> and O<sub>2</sub>? again in a relatively short (1,000 years or so) span of time, or would that be even more difficult and take a lot longer than getting the object where we wanted in the first place?

In short, the question is, can icy space objects be used to create planetary atmosphere for terraforming?  It's always seemed so, to me, but I'm curious if my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: The mirror idea might be problematic. 50 AU from the Sun the light is only 1/2500 of that on Earth. I think one needs nuclear power out there, or maybe in situ chemical fuel production.

Comment: Why stop at 1 Kuiper Belt object? 

Scale it up! Earth, and Earthlings probably have the math, and the computational ability to use gravity to execute a 'cascade' effect. We steal momentum every time Oberth manoeuvre is used. Do it the other way around with time in your favour. A few lifetimes down the line there could be N KB objects barging into Mars' orbit - all having started from a smaller body. Of course, to say the least, we would need a fairly detailed map (mass+orbit) of KB objects to begin with!

Comment: If we wanted to get really creative, we could move Ceres and turn it into a permanent moon for Mars, but I thought that might be pushing it.   Mars already has 2 moons, but they're really small.   Ceres in the right orbit might make mars feel more earth-like and it could generate some tides.

Comment: Something similar was explored by Issac Asimov, ["The Martian Way"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_Way) (1952)

Comment: Personally, I think the Asteroid Belt would be a more viable candidate. Kuiper Belt is simply enormous and so the objects are sparsely distributed, never mind the needed delta-V. The Asteroid Belt is much closer to Mars, its objects are much less sparsely distributed, and the same cascade scenario would be much easier to execute, never mind much less time needed and less impact energy (which would be a problem for Mars - the impact of 30km/s creates 1% the energy of one at 300km/s and these are the orders of velocities you'd be dealing with, choosing between AB and KB.

Comment: If Phobos has ices internally, how about pushing it towards Mars? @SF.

Comment: How long are you willing to wait ?

Comment: @Antzi obviously for such a project, it's a long term game-plan.   Basic orbital speed, it would take many decades minimum, maybe a few hundred years maybe a few thousand taking into account enormous energy required.   Perhaps even more if you tried to do it with giant mirrors and heating up one side of the icy-object.     I just thought it would make Mars more earth like if we gave it a moon.   I like the idea in a cosmetic sense, though I admit, a bit of a silly question on my part.

Comment: @SF Asteroid belt objects would be easier, but outside of Ceres, none are big enough to entertain me.    Also, I like the icy surface of KBOs because as the ice is melted by the sun some of the gas could fall towards Mars giving Mars some atmosphere over time.      The larger Kuiper belt objects are quite a bit bigger and mostly ice covered, but ultimately, your idea might still be the easier approach.   Ceres for example is smaller than Charon.    http://www.windows2universe.org/our_solar_system/dwarf_planets/images/dwarf_planet_sizes_big.jpg

Comment: @LocalFluff: Relatively easy, but it's just a single pebble respective to the needs.

Comment: @userLTK: Instead of single big, you should be looking at thousands of smaller ones. And a lot of them contain ice.

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient to use metal dense asteroids instead to increase the planet gravity and warm up the core?

Comment: I'd say go with 10 or 20 icey objects in the asteroid belt or between Jupiter and Neptune equal to your original object.  Using a spacecraft and ion engine as a tug you can adjust them slowly to sling passed one of the planets toward your intended destination.  Also there are comets coming through on a regular basis and they can be gravity tugged with a space craft to be captured as well.

Comment: If the Kuiper Belt object is very, very small, it might be possible to move it. But it is a very long distance from Kuiper Belt to Mars. Using the technology and resources available today, it is very difficult to move a space ship to the Kuiper Belt. But going back to Mars is impossible with current technology.

Comment: The biggest problem I see with this is not actually moving the object but the logistics of the timing of doing it. If you are going to crash something into the planet, especially of the sizes you are talking about, you are going to want to do it before the planet is populated but who's going to finance such a thing and wait such a long time if their aren't already people there? If there are already people there then even much smaller objects could be potentially catastrophic if off by even a little bit. Seems like you'd need to capture something in orbit for this to work.

Answer (score 13):

[Here](http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~mfogg/zubrin.htm) Robert Zubrin and Christopher McKay talk about terraforming Mars. Have your browser find "Moving Ammonia Asteroids" and it will take you to the relevant section about 3/4 down the page.

Zubrin and McKay talk about using a gravity assist. But using Saturn's gravity to toss down a 2.8 kilometer Centaur, not Neptune's gravity to toss down a 240 kilometer KBO. They figure .3 km/s would suffice to nudge an ice-teroid close enough to Saturn to throw it Mars-ward.

They also suggest vaporizing the asteroid's volatiles for the reaction mass. To accomplish this they propose a "quartet of 5000 MW nuclear thermal rocket engines". That's 20 giga-watts. The Palo Verde power plant is the largest nuclear power plant in the U.S. It is about 3.3 giga-watts.

So they're proposing sending the equivalent of 6 Palo Verde nuclear power plants out past Saturn. Not very plausible, in my opinion.

You seem to be talking about an object about a million times more massive than Zubrin and McKay's pebble. Let's say we could send it to Mars by nudging it near Neptune. For around .3 km/s, like Z & M's scheme. You'd need 20 million giga-watts. Sunlight's power density out among the KBOs is about 1/1000 of what we enjoy. You would need a very large mirror.

Then what happens at impact? An object falling from 30 A.U. would strike Mars at about 10 km/s (at least). It'd have a kinetic energy of about 50 mega-joules per kilogram. I believe most of the cometary volatiles would escape Mars. The impact would also probably blast off all Mars' CO2 atmosphere above the tangent plane at impact.

Terraforming Mars via volatile rich asteroids pre-supposes we could send massive power sources to the asteroids and establish extensive onsite infra-structure.

If we had this ability, why not just use the asteroidal volatiles where they sit? Developing the small bodies would give us far more real estate and natural resources than the outer surface of Mars. I make this argument in more detail at [Terraforming Mars vs Orbital Habs](http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2014/02/terraforming-mars-vs-orbital-habs.html).

Comment: Thank you for that.  Great answer.   I do want to point out, that, while it would be enormously difficult, a 120 mile radius icy space rock could create 1 ATM on mars, and you'd gain much more real estate than you'd give up.   You lose real estate when you move many smaller objects to create the atmosphere but 1 big one and you come out significantly ahead.  Still, I enjoyed your articles very much.  Some very good points.   Also, I think, the goal with a big one would be a near miss and close orbit around where the ice-object would break apart, not a crash land, but that's a minor point.

Comment: Might be a better idea to use mass drivers to lauch small chunks of a Jovian moon, small enough not to leave major craters when they hit.  (Assumes you have workable nuclear fusion as a power source, and cheap self-replicating machinery.)  As for the drawbacks of in situ use: 1) Claustrophobia - would you want to spend your life shut up in a tin can? 2) Difficulty of creating a sustainable biosphere in that small a space; 3) Leaks.

Comment: @userLTK For planetary surfaces heat and pressure are obstacles that prevent burrowing too deep. This is no obstacle for asteroids, we could burrow right through the middle. The entire *volume* is accessible, not just the outer surface. I believe this is true even for Vesta. Ceres' center might have too much heat and pressure, but much of Ceres' volume would still be accessible.

Comment: All good points.   The one thing Mars could give us (well, maybe, maybe not), that an asteroid or icy object can't is stuff like a sky, waterfalls, forests, wild animals, open space.   We like those things, at least, I like those things.

Though, probably smaller settlements come first.   They're certainly easier.

Comment: @HopDavid: Burrowing into an asteroid for living space assumes that humans, and the rest of their life support ecosystem, can survive indefinitely (and reproduce!) in near-zero gravity.  Since IIRC the longest duration human space flight so far is under 15 months, I'd say it still remains to be seen whether or not this is possible.

Comment: @jamesqf spinhabs can provide gravity.

Comment: @userLTK The can interiors can be quite spacious. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder  I don't expect to see such things any time soon. But terraforming Mars is even more implausible.

Comment: @HopDavid: Certainly you can spin a habitat for gravity, but that seems to contradict burrowing into the interior of an asteroid.  I doubt that you could spin up an asteroid to provide gravity, as so far most seem weakly cemented.  If you have an O'Neill type spinning habitat, you're back to the problem of supporting a permanent ecosystem in a leaky tin can.  Either would work as bases (like the Antarctic bases), not so well for permanent habitation.

Comment: Nowhere have I suggested a spin hab could be constructed by merely burrowing. With mining and manufacturing, spin habs can be made from asteroidal materials. Would O'Neill cylinders leak? Sure. So would Mars. With it's weak gravity and lack of magnetic field, Mars would lose its atmosphere over time.

Comment: @HopDavid: Sure, but starting from an initial breathable atmosphere, Mars would leak down to unbreathable in maybe 100 million years.  Making a rough guess from ISS experience, O'Neill-type habitats might take 10-100 years or so.  Terraforming is much more likely to create something sustainable, when we're talking about having multiple generations living there.

Comment: @jamesqf If a civilization is capable of diverting large asteroids to terraform Mars, I doubt their orbital habs would be as small, cramped and leaky as the I.S.S.

Comment: 5000MW powerplant is similar to a single EPR core output (4500)

Comment: The 20 giga-watts seems excessive, I'd think using a spacecraft with an ion propulsion engine especially a VASIMR that can use pretty much anything for fuel would be better.  Have the craft grab a large boulder from the surface of the ice-teroid, move away from the ice-teroid and hold position with the VASIMR and act as a gravity tug.  Aim for any planet between the current location and Mars to act as a slingshot to aid in getting you there at the right speeds/trajectory and you have a relatively cheap method for getting your ice-teroid to Mars.

Comment: @BrooksNelson So show me the math.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_tractor#Example From this example 100 m asteriod is moved with a 20 ton space craft over 10 years with 1,000 kg of reaction mass to avoid a collision with Earth.  If we decide on an ice-teroid 10 times more massive in a Lagrange point of one of the gas giants, I'd say a 200 ton space craft (or boulders picked up equal to that weight), and 10,000 kg of reaction mass (which could be volatiles from the actual ice-teroid in the case of VASIMR) should suffice to move a Lagrange captured ice-teroid into a swing by trajectory of the parent planet towards Mars.

Comment: @BrooksNelson From your link: "a velocity correction of 1 cm/s". Deflecting an asteroid from impact to near miss takes a minute amount of delta V. Dropping a Jupiter Trojan to a 1.52 A.U. perihelion would take about 4.3 km/s.    
And a 3100 meter asteroid would provide only a tiny fraction of the volatiles needed.

Comment: Moving a 3100 meter ice-teroid out of an already gravitationally balanced Lagrange point toward the host planet should also take a minute amount of delta V. The planet itself, and even potentially another of the planet's moons, would be used make up a large chunk of the delta V budget.  3100 m and OP mentioned a 120 km would suffice, so about 40 more should do it.

Comment: @BrooksNelson writes "Moving a 3100 meter ice-teroid out of an already gravitationally balanced Lagrange point toward the host planet should also take a minute amount of delta V." No. Perhaps you're buying into the Interplanetary SuperHighway. It is [overhyped](http://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2015/04/potholes-on-interplanetary-superhighway.html). At any rate it is L1 and L2 necks that are the hubs. Comet Oterma falls through the Sun Jupiter L1 and L2 necks occasionally. But doesn't make it as far down as Mars.

Comment: @BrooksNelson "3100 meter ice-teroid... OP mentioned 120 km would suffice, so about 40 more should do it." No, mass scales with $r^3$. You'd need $40^3$ more or about 64000. And even a 120 km asteroid is insufficient I suspect.

Comment: My understand of Lagrange points is objects are balanced between two bodies, a planet and a moon or a planet and the sun.  If you nudge an object toward one of the bodies and out of the L point, it will continue to fall toward that body.  If we use the low delta V of the nudge combined with a high delta V of a planned fly by of the planet that it was tied too we can add a lot of energy towards another destination that we didn't have before.  (Obviously we'd have to time this perfectly so we are heading in the right direction and we'd likely need more nudging once out of the L point.)

Comment: @BrooksNelson The balance at a Lagrange point is between three different accelerations. Gravity of central body, gravity of orbiting body and so called centrifugal force (a.k.a. inertia in a rotating frame). Nudge a Trojan away from Jupiter and the sun and centrifugal force would still be the major factors. The asteroid would remain at around 5.2 A.U. from the son.

Comment: But if you nudge it toward Jupiter and continue to 'tug' it's angle to create a near miss and slingshot it toward your destination and taking the free delta V from Jupiter, how is that not a less expensive way energetically to move asteroids around?

Comment: @BrooksNelson a Jupiter swing by looks like a hyperbola from Jupiter's point of view. And from Jupiter's POV, velocity on the incoming arm is the same as the velocity on the outgoing arm of the hyperbola. So if you have a Trojan approaching Jupiter at .3 km/s, it will depart from Jupiter at .3 km/s (from Jupiter's P.O.V.)

Comment: Similarly with a comet, with enough early warning and if the comet were going to pass 'close' to a planet we could 'tug' it closer to the planet to create a gravity assist to reduce the eccentricity and give us a more favorable orbit to potential put it to use.  Also we could 'wrap' the comet in a transparent encasement and leave a bell shaped rocket nossle shaped opening that we can use to 'rocket' it where we want when it is close enough to the sun to give off volatiles.

Comment: I'm not understanding how any gravity assisted missions, Voyager, Rosetta, etc. ever worked then?  Do they not use planets to increase their speed and change direction?  How would this not apply here?

Comment: @BrooksNelson An object's speed wrt Jupiter is not changed but direction is. Which results in a change of speed with regard to the sun. For something coming from earth, velocity wrt Jupiter is 5 or 6 km/s. Changing direction of a 5 km/s vector can result in a big delta V. Changing the direction of a .3 km/s delta V vector, not so much.

Comment: Two things, using an ice-teroid that is at a Lagrange point between one of the moons and Jupiter means you can take advantage of more delta V instead of just between Jupiter and the sun.  Since their orbits are moving faster  around Jupiter.  Also since these are sizeable ice-teroid there's a much better chance they are solids and not just rubble piles.  If so you could land a more traditional rocket on the surface and use a much higher ISP for a short burst at the highest velocity during the fly by to take advantage of the Oberth effect and add even more to your delta V on the cheap.

Comment: @BrooksNelson "Since their orbits are moving faster around Jupiter. " No, icesteroids at the Sun Jupiter and L4 and L5 regions are moving the same velocity as Jupiter, give or take a small amount.

Comment: I'm referring to an object like Calypso, caught at a Lagrange point between Tethys and Saturn, ie not with a planet and the Sun.  These bodies should have much more orbital velocities than their parent planets compared to the sun.

Comment: The question was about Kuiper Belt objects. Calypso isn't a KBO. And your new scenario ignores some of the points I made earlier. You are consuming too much of my time.